# Is it possible to use jade inside a local meteor package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

While trying to split up my meteor application in separate packages I encountered a problem when trying to encapsulate templates. The package name would be `gs-users`:

**packages/gs-users/package.js**

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');
    api.use('mquandalle:jade');
    api.addFiles('views/list.jade');
    api.addFiles('gs-users.js');
});
```

My template file **packages/gs-users/views/list.jade**:

```
template(name="GsUsersList")
    p Ola señior!!
```

Inside my main applications route definition (**lib/routes.js**):

```
Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('GsUsersList');
});
```

Meteor now complains: `Couldn't find a template named "GsUsersList" or "gsUsersList". Are you sure you defined it?`

When using the `templating` package instead of `mquandalle:jade` and .html files instead of .jade files inside the `gs-users` package everything works fine. But I really hate plain HTML ;)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but since you need to list all your files manually anyways, why not just compile them inside your template by manually calling the jade compiler?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is more simple than I thought. Just use `waitingkuo:jade` instead of `mquandalle:jade` and add `templating` as a dependency:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.3');
  api.use('waitingkuo:jade');
  api.use('templating');
  api.addFiles([
    'le-template.jade',
  ], ['client']);
});
```

Works like a charm!